# Some problems in the paper about minimal surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, vector-bundles, minimal-surfaces, line-bundles

I am reading the paper [Minimal surfaces of constant curvature in $S^n$,](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1999793) wrote by Professor Robert Bryant in 1985. In this paper, the author introduced some operators to give a new method in order to classify the minimal surfaces of constant ($>0$, $<0$ or $=0$) curvature in $\mathbb{S}^n$.

In section 1, the author gave the definitions of the 3 operators after introducing a complex line bundle, where I can hardly understand.

[image]

Question 1: In page 261, what is a "complex line bundle of $1$-forms"? I mean, what are the total space and the fibre of this bundle? Also, why the complex line bundle can be the multiples of a $1$-form $\omega$ since these two concepts are totally different?

Question 2: In the line 6 in the page 261, why any section $\sigma$ of $\tau^m$ can be write as $$\sigma=s(\omega)^m$$ for a unique function $s$ on the bundle of oriented orthonormal frames?

Question 3: In the line 7 in the page 261, why we have $$ds=-mi\rho s+s'\omega+s''\bar{\omega}?$$

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me!

Comment: A complex line bundle is a vector bundle, where each fiber is a $1$-dimensional complex vector space. A complex line bundle of complex $1$-forms is a complex $1$-dimensional subbundle of $\mathbb{C}\otimes T^*M$. In the specific situation here, $\tau$ is the complex line bundle where for each $x \in M$, $$ \tau_x = \{ c\omega(x):\ c \in \mathbb{C} \} \subset \mathbb{C}\otimes T_x^*M. $$  If $k > 0$, then, $$\tau^k = \tau\otimes\tau\cdots\tau,$$ where there are $k$ factors of $\tau$.

Comment: @Deane Thanks a lot! Now I can understand most of this construction. However, why the author can compute that $ds=-mi\rho s+s'\omega+s''\bar{\omega}$?

Comment: That's a bit trickier. I suggest writing everything in terms of local coordinates. An important point is that the forms and functions are all on $\mathcal{F}$ and not on $M$. For example, $\rho, \omega. \overline\omega$ are differential forms on $\mathcal{F}$ and not on $M$.

Comment: @Deane Yes, the author omits the pull-back notation. However, I tried to write everything in local coordinates, but I still have no idea about the identity. Could you explain more precisely? Anyway, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: The point is that since $\sigma$ is a well-defined section of $\tau^m$, you should deduce that $s(e^{i\theta}\xi) = e^{-im\theta)s(\xi)$ (or something like that). You have to think about differentiation along the fiber; the other two terms come from the horizontal stuff.

Comment: @TedShifrin I have the following calculations: $$\nabla \sigma=\nabla(s\omega^m)=(ds)\omega^m+s\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\omega^k\otimes\nabla\omega\otimes\omega^{m-k-1}=(ds)\omega^m+mi\rho s\omega^m.$$ If this is right, then it suffices to explain why $\nabla\sigma$ can be written as $(s'\omega+s''\bar{\omega})\omega^m$.